# Change order status using cron job in command line

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to change order status using cron(in my local progect)
I know only this command

```
php cron.php -m default
```

Where cron.php in root of magento 
What next? Please help me, I have not worked with cron tab yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new simple extension.  See for example [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

Then add in the configuration the cron job listener:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <amasty_example>
            <schedule><cron_expr>3 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>example/observer::doSomething</model></run>
        </amasty_example>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

The main part in your case is Observer.php  that be called by cron every hour at 0:03  1:03  2:03 ...

```
class Amasty_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function doSomething($observer)
    {
        //add your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it does not help me becouse I need to do this in command line...

Comment: Once you have the module activated, you can call the  `php cron.php` in the command line and it calls your code.

Comment: Wow.... Is It really works like this? Thank you man, you saved my nerves

Comment: Yes, Magento uses it's own scheduling algorithms.  It requires you to call one crop.php script and then it call all module listeners based on the schedule in the config file.  Pls mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question.